# Is there a way to implement passport.js google authentication to flutter?

Tags: node.js, dart, flutter, passport.js

I have a website that is running on nodejs with passport.js to authenticate users with google OAuth.

I am trying to create a flutter application for my website is there anyway i can authenticate users on mobile with their already existing records in my database?

i tried to research about this topic but no page seem to have the answer.

Comment: I have not used passport.js but as far as I understand it, it's just middleware for node.js
So, all you have to do is sending a request from your mobile app to your node.js server and take care of the rest on your server side. A mobile device sending requests to a server is nothing different than a browser sending requests.
An alternative would be Google Firebase, but then you would loose your single database, since Firebase has it's own user storage.

Comment: the middleware redirects the user to google auth, what is the equivalent way of doing it on mobile? should i open it in webview or something?

Comment: Yes, that would be the easiest way.

Comment: Ok thank you, ill go with this and see how it ends up

Comment: did u find the solution ?